# Issue with Masonry - Images load vertically at first, then rearrange.

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-masonry, masonry

Example - http://paulmatheson.net/photography/nature.html

My masonry code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $container = jQuery('#masonry-grid'); 
$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
  $container.masonry({
    columnWidth: 240,
    gutter: 10,
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
  });
  $container.imagesLoaded.done( function(instance) {
    $container.masonry('layout');
  });
});
```

Am I incorrectly calling it?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**
Your `$container.imagesLoaded.done` function is incorrect, it is `$container.imagesLoaded().done`. It is also inside the `$container.imagesLoaded(function()` which it should not be. You don't need to call imagesloaded twice like this and layout masonry again..

Your original imagesloaded code here:

```
var $container = jQuery('#masonry-grid'); 
$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
$container.masonry({
columnWidth: 240,
gutter: 10,
itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
$container.imagesLoaded.done( function(instance) {
$container.masonry('layout');
});
});
```

Needs to be:

```
var $container = jQuery('#masonry-grid'); 
$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
$container.masonry({
columnWidth: 240,
gutter: 10,
itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

});
I would also suggest loading imagesloaded.js before masonry.js

If you really have to use the done method, you could use this code:

```
var $container = jQuery('#masonry-grid'); 
$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
$container.masonry({
columnWidth: 240,
gutter: 10,
itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});

}).done( function(instance) {
$container.masonry('layout');
});
```

Comment: I've changed the code - It's hard to tell on my end if it's working, though. Can you verify? It still looks like it loads vertically albeit much more quickly.

Comment: Hmm, I must be doing something completely wrong. For instance, check here where the images are larger and so the effect is more noticeable - http://paulmatheson.net/design.html I changed the code to your recommended code and the issue persists.

Comment: I'm not sure why your loading masonry and then doing an additional  layout on `.done()`. Did you try the code without the done function?

Comment: This may not be part of your issue but you have your masonry containers with the same id, `id="masonry-grid"`. id's must always be unique, only classes can be used multiple times. Each of your grids must have a different id.

Comment: I just want to point out that `.grid-item` has a background. `{
    background-color: #373c48;
}` This background color is probably what the op @pmath325 sees while the images are being loaded prior to masnory layout firing.

Comment: Good call! I noticed but didn't connect that to the issue.